# Cant see image when source written in CSS

Tags: css

I can't see this image when the page is viewed in my browser.

my CSS code is;

```
#bar {  
background:url("/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/images/bar.png");
}
```

and the div section is;

```
<div id="bar">
</div>
```

Can you see why i would see nothing in my browser, have i made a error.

Thankyou

Comment: Your div has no dimensions.

Comment: Well, if that is all of the code, I'd say it is because the height of the `div` is 0. Add some padding or a specific height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put a size on the div. It's size is non-existent since it has no content... it doesn't use the background to determine the size since it's capable of repeating, etc.

You can set `height` on the element with this:

```
#bar {
 background:url("/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/images/bar.png");
 height:300px; /*Use the value you want can be the height of the background image*/
}
```

Comment: sorry i am new to this, how would i do this?

Comment: In your #bar CSS style, add width and height properties that match the dimensions you want. http://jsfiddle.net/BC9YB/

Comment: width isn't necessary just height.

Comment: `#bar:grabRightBorder::pullHardRight(800px); cssEngine::sipCoffee()`

Comment: Okay thanks this worked, would you know if it is possible to stretch a bar/image whilst keeping its height the same, so the height is fixed but the width changes when the browser scaled? Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set your width and height to arbitrary values in your css, let's say:

```
#bar {  
background:url("/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/images/bar.png") 
width: 600px;
height: 800px;
}
```

Also, in your html, add something to the div, such as a non-breaking space `&nbsp;`

```
<div id="bar">&nbsp;</div>
```